# How to configure QuestDB in embedded mode?

Tags: questdb

The embedded mode only gives a DefaultCairoConfiguration which is completely different from server.conf, is there a proper way to configure embedded QuestDB in Java application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend [DefaultCairoConfiguration](https://javadoc.questdb.io/io.questdb/io/questdb/cairo/defaultcairoconfiguration#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.CharSequence)) or implement [CairoConfiguration](https://javadoc.questdb.io/io.questdb/io/questdb/cairo/cairoconfiguration). Alternatively, there is PropServerConfiguration, but it's not meant to be used in embedded API (yet, it's possible to do so).

The reference for the configuration parameters is available at https://questdb.io/docs/reference/configuration/